# Pass params to q.defer (d3.csv)

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

How do you pass params to q.defer in d3?
I need to pass an index( file name - **d** ) here:

```
    var data = [1,3,5,6,7];
        var q = d3.queue();
        data.map(function(d){
            q.defer(d3.csv,'https://***/'+d+'.csv', d); //something like pass d
        })
        q.awaitAll(function(error, result, d) {//and get the d here according to results
                      if (error) throw error;
//how to get the d value here?
    });
```

Is there a way to get the d inside the awaitAll|
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only through the parent scope:

```
var myd = data.map(function(d){
    q.defer(d3.csv,'https://***/'+d+'.csv', d); 
    return d
})

q.awaitAll(function(error, result, d) {
    if (error) throw error;
    //how to get the d value here?
    console.log(myd) // myd contains all the d from your map.
});
```

But since in the `data.map()` call, you are already using all of `data` (`data` is bound to `d` inside the mapper function):

```
q.awaitAll(function(error, result, d) {
    if (error) throw error;
    //how to get the d value here?
    console.log(data) // this is the same `data` from the `data.map()`
});
```

EDIT: the original question was not clear. The OP apparently wants to remap the results back to a `d` value:

```
q.awaitAll(function(error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    //how to get the d value here?
    result.map(function(res, idx) {
        console.log("original d:" + data[idx].toString())
    }
});
```

awaitAll documentation: https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_awaitAll

Some additional reading material:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript

https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: yes, but I need result according to d value. As I understand the "result" is always in random order, as it is a thread, or am I wrong?

Comment: `results` is an array of all of the defers you made. `results[0]` corresponds to `data[0]` corresponds to `d == 1`.

Comment: thanks, I thought that as it is async then the results order will be random

Comment: awaitAll waits for all defers to finish, and yields the result of each defer into `results` in the callback. https://github.com/d3/d3-queue#queue_awaitAll This is a similar to jQuery's `.when().done()`